# Java API for solving Linear expression with one variable

Tags: java, linear-algebra, algebra, linear-equation

Is there any standard Java API for solving Linear expressions with one variable as following example:

- x*1/40+5 = 12.45
- x*635/(27*1024) = 52
- x^2-3.4/6 = 43
- 3+logx-13 = 15

I tried to solve it with  `Apache Common Math` library but the Matrix and cramer's method are for Biliear and trilinear equations.

Comment: Solving means root finding in all the cases you've cited.  I'd recommend looking at root finding algorithms.

Comment: @duffymo. With the added benefit that all these cases have very clear analytical solutions.

Comment: wile an interesting problem, this is explicitly an off topic question.